# Code for calculating instances where the condition is true

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, vector, comparison

Recently I was going through [this](https://www.codechef.com/ZCOPRAC/problems/ZCO13003) codechef problem while practicing for the upcoming zoc.

The problem asks to calculate number of combinations of the given numbers where the sum is greater than another given number.

Previously I had a bruteforce algorithm which gave the correct answer but took a lot of time , in some cases even more than a second which raised a TLE error in codechef.

So I changed my whole algorithm to get rid of that TLE error but now it only gives correct answer for the first test and rest of them produce wrong outputs , can someone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong here :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<long long> tstCases;
    std::vector<long long> okset;
    std::vector<long long> testset;
    for(int i =0;i<2;i++){
        long long cases;
        std::cin >> cases;
        tstCases.push_back(cases);
    }
    long long n = tstCases.at(0);
    long long k = tstCases.at(1);
    for(long long i =0;i<n;i++){
        long long cases;
        std::cin >> cases;
        if(cases<=k){
            if(cases < k/2){
                okset.push_back(cases);
            }else{
                testset.push_back(cases);
            }
        }
    }
    long long l = okset.size();
    long long p1 = (l*(l-1))/2;
    long long p2 = 0;
    if(l > 0){
        for(long long i =0;i<l;i++){
            for(long long j =0;j<testset.size();j++){
                if(okset.at(i)+testset.at(j) >= k){
                    break;
                }else{
                    p2++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    long long p = p1+p2;
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

**Note :** I am using `long long` because the problem instructed me to do so and I am lazy enough to do it by myself so I used replace all. Sorry for that.

Comment: Why are you using a break conditon, there can be more values that satisfy the condition that can be present as you have not sorted the `testset` vector.

Comment: ahh , now i remember , i have wriiten that sorted thing in paper but not in code. thanks

Comment: hmm still the code fails to pass the last test within the given time limit as a result I get a TLE , still I have to improve the algorithm ,gosh , well I can say I have learnt a bit of Asymtotic analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like I havent sorted the testset array thus many items are left after that break statement. Thanks [uSeemSurprised](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2955869/useemsurprised) to help me notice that.